# Combine Ionic `onHold` and Angularjs `ng-click` to select element

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-directive

In my current ionic App, I have some box that I want to select them exactly in the form of select chat in **Telegram**, That means:

**1.** At first I start select box by **[OnHold](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/)** gesture in ionic,
    *This work correctly*.

**2.** After that I want to select or deselect box by **click** on each of them, *This is not working*

**[There is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mortezaQo/browomk2/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="box" select-box>box 1</div>
  <div class="box" select-box>box 2</div>
  <div class="box" select-box>box 3</div>
</ion-content>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
app.directive("selectBox", ["$ionicGesture", "$rootScope",
  function($ionicGesture, $rootScope) {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

          // onHold => start select box by `onHold` => working good
          $ionicGesture.on('hold', function() {
            elem.addClass("selected");
            $rootScope.startSelect = true; // to enable select box by click
          }, elem);

          // after start select box in `onHold` gesture => 
          // select box by click => not working
          if ($rootScope.startSelect) {
            elem.on("click", function() {
              if (elem.hasClass('selected')) {
                elem.removeClass("selected");
              } else {
                elem.addClass("selected");
              }
            });
          }

        } // link function

    } // return
  }
]); // directive

app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope",
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.startSelect = false;
  }
]);
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Now, How to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AngularJS documentation:

> Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the link option to register DOM listeners as well as update the DOM. It is executed after the template has been cloned and is where directive logic will be put.

Therefore, `link` is executed only once at the beginning. And so is the part where you check this: `if ($rootScope.startSelect) {...}`. You'll have to check if this value is `true` inside another listener for it to be executed every time. You can use `tap` gesture, for example:

```
$ionicGesture.on('tap', function() {
  if ($rootScope.startSelect) {
    if (elem.hasClass('selected')) {
      elem.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      elem.addClass('selected');
    }
  }
}, elem);
```

Notice that `$rootScope.selected` will remain `true` after the first `hold` event, so taping will act as a select too. Don't know if this is the functionality you look for.

Here's an updated fiddle with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/browomk2/2/